# Trek Verve 3 disk bike

Tags: wheels, front

Just purchased a Trek Verve 3 disk bike.  Had to take the front wheel off the get it in the car.  Put wheel back on when arrived home and took it out for a spin.  The front wheel makes a rubbing or grinding sound when I ride it.  Thought it was supposed to be a quiet ride.  What is going on?

Answer (score 3):

The first thing to check is if your wheel is slightly misaligned in the dropouts. Disk brake tolerances are pretty small. From the web it looks like the front wheel has a quick release. Try untightening the wheel and reseating it in the dropouts. 
If that doesn't fix the grinding noise, you should check if the pads have adjusted too far in or the brake rotor is slightly bent.

What can happen is that the brake lever was pressed in while the wheel was removed and the brake pads have auto-adjusted too far in. Generally, people put a special spacer in the brake when the wheel is removed to avoid this problem. The fix for this is pretty easy, use a soft plastic tool ( tire levers are good for this ) to slightly push each brake pad back until the inserted wheel rotates freely. Then pump the brakes hard several times to "reset" the auto adjust back to where it should be.

Lastly, the disk rotors might have gotten slightly bent during transport. ( dropping a wheel and having it land rotor side down is common.)

Pick front of the bike up and spin the wheel, watch the rotor in the brake an see if there are significant wobbles. Truing a disk rotor isn't the easiest task for a novice bike mechanic, but a good shop should help you with this for a newly purchased bike.